# Male equivalent of "maid", please?

Tags: word-choice

A friend plays Debussy's "Maid with Flaxen Hair" in a different key, and wants to call it a different name. I suggested "Lad with Flaxen Hair", but I'm not sure whether "lad" is exactly the male equivalent of "maid", as "boy" is to "girl".

I googled it, but few answers are relevant. I think the "maid" here is something just a little different from "girl", so what would you guys suggest as its male equivalent, please? Thank you!

Comment: You’re right that *maid* is very similar to *girl*, and conjures up images of a Julie Andrews singing blondely in the Alps. The reason it conjures up “girl” this way and not “woman” is because the word was reserved for *unmarried women*, especially those who looked marriageable (ie young and pretty, as opposed to an “old maid”). It’s this *unmarried* thing, especially its entailment of youth, which is the key to your puzzle. You need a word which means “young, attractive guy” or “marriage-eligible guy”.

Comment: I think a word for he former would be more fitting, but I can only offer a word for the latter: *bachelor*. It used to imply similar things to *maid*, but not as sharply (it sometimes had to be underscored with *eligible* bachelor).

Comment: *maid* formerly meant specifically that the woman was a virgin. you wouldn't find a parallel word with this connotation for boys since their status in this respect was never so important that they distinguished with a special word.

Comment: I'm sorry, but, despite a number of answers, how is a change of gender in the name related to a change of key in the piece itself?  First, the title of the piece is "La fille aux cheveux di lin".  The word 'fille' just means 'girl' with some other overtones, of which 'maid' is not one.  So why the change of gender?  What key has it moved to from the original G-Flat Major?  Is it now in a minor key instead?  That might affect the feeling enough to suggest a change of title.  But otherwise, what would be the point?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, "lad" would be fine to change gender.
The original title, [La fille aux cheveux de lin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_fille_aux_cheveux_de_lin), more than suggests that it is about a ["girl"](https://translate.google.com/?oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#auto/en/la%20fille). "Maid" was, for whatever reason, the word chosen for the English title by a publisher.
Of course, if one is free to change the gender of the subject , then one would also be free to change the character of the subject.

Comment: Because of this definition: "Maid:  A girl; a young (unmarried) woman; Now *arch*. and *regional*" (OED)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the *[Youth](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/youth) with the Flaxen Hair* as the title of your transposed and transgendered Debussy piece. A *youth* in the singular evokes the same era as *maid* and has the same connotation of romance.

*Lad* would be fine were it not for various modern associations: "Jack the lad," "He's a bit of a lad," "lads and ladettes."

Comment: This is it. This is the word which is counterpart to *maid*. It strictly meant *young man* and almost always *young unmarried man*.